# Disjoint curves in an algebraic surface

Tags: algebraic-curves, algebraic-surfaces, 4-manifolds

Let $X$ be an algebraic surface (over the complex) with $p_g=q=0$. Is it possible to have **disjoint** curves $C_1,\ldots, C_b$, of positive genus, spanning $H_2(X,{\mathbb Q})$, $b=b_2(X)$?

(When $X$ is the blow-up of the projective plane at some points, the exceptional divisors and a curve coming from the projective plane not passing through the points, give an answer if we do not assume the condition on the genus.)

Comment: I only have a couple of topological considerations: Donaldson's theorem forces the intersection form to be diagonal, and the assumption $p_g = q = 0$ pins it down to $\langle1\rangle+(b-1)\langle-1\rangle$ (if I'm not mistaken). The genus assumption says something about the canonical divisor (like pinning down the sign of most coefficients).

Comment: Yes, that's right. All of them should have negative self-intersection except one. However, I do not know even how to prove (or if it is true) that $X$ is minimal

Comment: This is easily seen to be impossible for $X = (\mathbb{P}^1)^2$; the genus condition is not even needed here.

Comment: Donaldson's theorem concerns *simply connected* 4-manifolds. However, there are (non rational) complex surfaces with $p_g=q=0$ that are *not* simply connected (for instance, the classical Godeaux surface), so in this case I do not see how to conclude that the intersection form must be necessarily diagonalisable. 
I'm missing something?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: Donaldson's theorem works regardless of $\pi_1$. This was definitely proved by Frøyshov using Seiberg-Witten and by Ozsváth-Szabó using Heegaard Floer.

Comment: @MarcoGolla: do you have a reference?

Comment: This is the paper of Frøyshov's that I was thinking about: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1397685 . And this is the one by Ozsváth and Szabó: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1957829 .

Comment: This discussion is somewhat out of focus: the OP considers *rational* (co)homology. A quadratic form over $\Bbb{Q}$ is always diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you.

The following gives an answer in the case that all the curves are assume to have genus $g=1$, and $b\geq 2$.

One of the curves, say $C=C_1$ has $C^2>0$. As $p_g=q=0$ we have $\chi(O_X)=1-q+p_g=1$. By Riemann-Roch, we have $\chi(C)=1+ \frac12 (C^2-K\cdot C)$. As $C^2+K\cdot C=2g(C)-2=0$ (by adjunction), we have $\chi(C)=1+C^2$. Also as $h^0(K)=p_g=0$ and $C$ is effective, we have $h^2(C)=h^0(K-C)=0$. From the exact sequence $0\to O_X\to O_X(C) \to O_C(C)\to 0$, taking the long exact sequence in cohomology, we have $H^1(X,O(C))=H^1(C, O_C(C))$. If $C^2>0$ then the last group vanishes, hence $h^1(C)=0$. So $\chi(C)=h^0(C)=1+C^2>1$, and there is a pencil of curves of genus $1$. If necessary, blow up at points of $C$ to arrange $C^2=1$. The bundle $O_C(C)$ is of the form $O_C(p_0)$, for some point $p_0\in C$.
The pencil defined by the linear series $|C|$ is a pencil of genus $1$ curves passing through $p_0$. Blowing up at this point we get a surface $X'$ and a map $\pi:X'\to P^1$. Let $\sigma$ be the exceptional divisor, which is a rational curve of self-intersection $-1$. This gives the structure of an elliptic surface, possibly non-minimal, and containing all our genus $1$ curves. Blow down any $(-1)$-curve in a fiber of $\pi$ to get a minimal elliptic surface $X''\to P^1$. This has $q=0, p_g=0$ and it has a section (the image of $\sigma$). By the Enriques-Kodaira classification, this has to be a rational surface. Any section of a minimal elliptic surface has to have self-intersection $-1$ (let $s$ be a section; the canonical bundle is $K=-f$; then $s^2+K\cdot s=-2$, so $s^2=-1$). So $\sigma$ cannot intersect any rational curve being blown-down when going from $X'$ to $X''$, since otherwise its self-intersection increases. All the genus one surfaces $C_i\subset X$ give genus one surfaces $C_i'\subset X'$ which map down to $C_i''\subset X''$. These must be fibers (any curve not intersecting $C$ is contained in a fiber, so it is a rational curve or a fiber). This means that $C_i''$ intersect $\sigma$,
and hence $C_i'$ intersects $\sigma$. When going to $X$, $C_i$ intersects $C$. Contradiction!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is clearly affirmative for $b=1$, which unfortunately corresponds *only* to 101 surfaces, including ${\mathbb P}^2$. I doubt that there is a single other case in which it works.

Indeed I do not know a single example with $b>1$ for which your statement holds. It clearly fails for $({\mathbb P}^1)^2$, as mentioned by ulrich, and a similar argument shows that it fails for all surfaces constructed in [BCG](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610267).
I can easily prove that it fails for a bunch of the surfaces constructed by me and some of my collaborators (listed in my survey published [here](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-319-13861-9)). As noticed by Marco, when the answer is affirmative, you can contract all the *negative* curves, obtaining what is called ${\mathbb Q}-$homology plane. The smooth ones (corresponding to the case $b=1$) have been recently classified by Prasad-Yeung/Cartwright-Steger and give the 101 surfaces mentioned above. The classification of the singular ones is a big open problem, but the only known examples have rational singularities, so do not fill your assumption on the genus. The most recent paper on this subject is [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02104).

Comment: Is it automatic that for all these surfaces there is a holomorphic curve representing some nontrivial homology class? Also, why can you always contract negative curves? (This could well be a standard argument I am not aware of...)

Comment: These surfaces are projective, hence $H^2(S,\Bbb{Q})$ is spanned by the class of an ample divisor. And, yes, a  curve of negative square on a smooth surface can always be contracted.

Comment: The assumption $p_g=0$ gives $h^2(X,{\mathbb C})=h^{1,1}$ and therefore $H^2(X,{\mathbb Q}) \subset H^{1,1}$: these surfaces have automatically maximal Picard number.